# Use directory path of target in list of prerequisites in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I wrote a script that takes in two files ending in .cfg and outputs a file ending in .cmp.  I want to include this in my Makefile because a few source code files depend on this .cmp file.

In my Makefile, I want to do this:

```
%.cmp: %.cfg $(dir %)/default.cfg
    ./compare.pl $^ $@
```

There are two dependencies to generate the .cmp file.  First is a .cfg file with the same name, and second is a .cfg file which is *always* named default.  Both .cfg files and the output .cmp file will be in the same directory.

Is there a way to grab the directory path of the target and use it with the prereqs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess [Secondary Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion) is probably what you're looking for:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.cmp: %.cfg $$(dir %)default.cfg
    ./compare.pl $^ $@
```

Also note the absence of slash after `$$(dir %)`, `dir` function always append one to the resulting value.