# getting the target name in a function in prerequisites list [makefile]

Tags: gcc, makefile

I'm trying to create a makefile where the target is used to search for dependencies in .d

Thanks to the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488256/use-directory-path-of-target-in-list-of-prerequisites-in-makefile) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705974/referring-to-the-target-name-from-the-list-of-the-prerequisites) I have discovered that `.SECONDEXPANSION:` does the job. However I'm running into an issue nesting functions which is seemingly bizarre. The offending rule looks like this:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(APPS): %: $$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$$(wildcard $$@.d/*.c)) $$(INC_OBJS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

instead of:

`gcc -Wall -std=c99 unittest.d/unittest.o common/cards.o -o unittest`

which is what I want, I get:

`gcc -Wall -std=c99 unittest.d/unittest.c common/cards.o -o unittest`

which for some reason doesn't have the `.o` substituted for the `.c`. So it appears I'm almost there, I just need to get the substitution working. All help appreciated and if you think this is a poor way to organize a makefile, critizism on that front welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to use `%` as two different wildcards at once, the static pattern stem and the `patsubst` wildcard. So Make makes the stem replacement and gets this:

```
$(patsubst unittest.c,unittest.o,$(wildcard $@.d/*.c))
```

and then `patsubst` does nothing, because it finds no "unittest.c" to replace. (Note that the "unittest.c" in "unittest.d/unittest.c" doesn't match, because without a wildcard, `patsubst` looks for a perfect match.)

There's no need for this to be a static pattern rule (you never use that functionality), so you can just eliminate that part and the rest should work:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(APPS): $$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$$(wildcard $$@.d/*.c)) $$(INC_OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

Comment: that did it! I think I see what you are saying but why wouldn't it become `$(patsubst unittest.c,unittest.o,$(wildcard $@.d/*.c))`? since the pattern (target) is unittest?

Comment: @Luis: Sorry, my mistake, I skimmed the question too quickly. You're right, I'll edit...

Comment: This solution does not work unless you force `%` to be expanded later. This can be achieved by defining `p:=%` and then to replace `%` in patsubst with `p`. Secondary expansion is definitely required.

Comment: @null: I don't understand your comment. The solution above *does* work.